# RESTEasy authentication and authorization

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to add authentication and authorization in my RESTEasy application.

This is my service method which I want to limit to users with 'admin' role:

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@PUT
@Path("/hosts/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response updateHost(@PathParam("id") int id) {
```

And this is my interceptor

```
@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
  {
```

However, my filter method does not get called and the authorization for updateHost is not done. After reading the docs, my understanding is @Provider on SecurityInterceptor will make sure that its filter method gets called after a request is received.
Can anyone help me figure out why it is not being called?

Answer (score 3):

I found that we need to enable the role based security in the web deployment descriptor:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```